# EarlGrey launches the APP but the screen is blank

Tags: ios, testing, earlgrey

Trying to launch EarlGrey tests on my APP but all that I get is empty screen after the splash screen is opened.

We use 2 different windows for splash screen and main APP and it looks like EarlGrey stacks on the first one. Is there a way to switch the screens in EarlGrey?

That what I have in test output:

> 2016-03-03 15:00:25.721 XING[23504:165847] Could not kickstart com.apple.AXInspector [268435460 - port: 31499]
>   2016-03-03 15:00:49.001 XING[23504:165847] Application window hierarchy (ordered by window level, from front to back):

Legend:
[Window 1] = [Frontmost Window]
[AX] = [Accessibility]

========== Window 1 ==========

> UITextEffectsWindow:0x7fbe3bf10e50; AX=N; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; AX.activationPoint={187.5, 333.5}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; alpha=1>
>     UIInputSetContainerView:0x7fbe3bc2cff0; AX=N; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; AX.activationPoint={187.5, 333.5}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; opaque; alpha=1>
>     UIInputSetHostView:0x7fbe3bc24550; AX=N; AX.frame={{0, 667}, {375, 0}}; AX.activationPoint={187.5, 667}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 667}, {375, 0}}; opaque; alpha=1>

========== Window 2 ==========

> UIWindow:0x7fbe3be22b80; AX=N; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; AX.activationPoint={187.5, 333.5}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; opaque; alpha=1>
>     |--UIView:0x7fbe3d55d970; AX=N; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; AX.activationPoint={187.5, 333.5}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; opaque; alpha=1>

Comment: EarlGrey shouldn't be messing up with the order of these windows. You might have something going on in the way the app is launched for testing. You can directly set breakpoints and see how the window is created in your app delegate. UITextEffectsWindow is an internal window and it's fine for it to be on top of other windows. The only relevant window is UIWindow:0x7fbe3be22b80 which doesn't seem to have any children (as per the hierarchy) so you might want to see where that window is created and contents of the root view controller that's set on that window.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer. I was able to found a problem, there was a specific setting for all the UnitTests in our APP. Disabling of those helped to launch the APP properly.

Comment: Could you please describe what exactly you changed? Otherwise, there's no value for anybody but you.