# EarlGrey launches APP with black screen

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, automated-tests, earlgrey

After successfully adding `EarlGrey` to existing project (using `CocoaPods`) project is successfully built (both "for running" and "for testing"). The problem is that if I run the app from XCode it runs as expected. If I run it as a test only splash screen appears and then whole screen turns black. Have anyone encountered such issue? What might be a problem here?

There is somewhat similar question [Black screen with EarlGrey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774280/earlgrey-launches-the-app-but-the-screen-is-blank) but author did not share his solution.

Additional info:

- XCode 8
- CocoaPods 1.2.1
- EarlGrey 1.9.3

Comment: Are there any logs you could please provide us to debug? Do you have a continuous animation or network request going on? EarlGrey will wait for it to complete before proceeding to the next step.

Comment: You may want to debug your app delegate and see if it's behaving differently under normal runs and test runs. I would guess that the window or its root view controller isn't being set property. There could also be some issue related to resource loading (storyboard or xib).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed @khandpur advice and tried debugging my app first. So I found out, that in `main.m` file we're checking if current run is a test run, by

`BOOL areWeRunningTests = NSClassFromString(@"XCTestCase") != nil;`

Based on that we are running app differently.

To everyone in similar situation: I've added a check

`BOOL areWeRunningUITests = NSClassFromString(@"EarlGreyImpl") != nil;`

and if that's true app is starting normally.

**Final comments** - you have to know your app a little to be able to use EarlGrey easily... :)